# How to make the array of the alphabet to rotate from "z" to "a" (ruby)

Tags: ruby

I am doing a Caesar cipher. I thought that the unless statement will work but it doesn't with or without then. Then I changed the unless with if and put ; in the place of then and it reads : undefined method `>' for nil:NilClass.

```
def caesar_cipher(input, key)
    input.each do |x| 
        numbers = x.ord + key.to_i unless (numbers > 122) then numbers = x.ord + key - 26
        letters = numbers.chr
        print letters
    end
end

puts "Write the words you want to be ciphered: "
input = gets.chomp.split(//)
puts "Write the key (1 - 26): "
key = gets.chomp
caesar_cipher(input,key)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you write a branch with condition (`if` or `unless`) at the end of a line, after an initial statement, there are two things that apply and affect you:

- The condition is assessed *before* the statement on its left. In your case that means `numbers` has not been assigned yet so it is `nil`.
- The branch decision is whether or not to run the initial statement, you do not branch to the statement after the `then`.

You can solve this simply by converting your condition to an `if` and moving it to a separate line:

```
def caesar_cipher(input, key)
    input.each do |x| 
        numbers = x.ord + key.to_i 
        if (numbers > 122)
           numbers = x.ord + key - 26
        end
        letters = numbers.chr
        print letters
    end
end
```

There are arguably better ways of coding this cipher in Ruby, but this should solve your immediate problem.

Answer (score 3):

Here are a couple of Ruby-like ways to write that:

**#1**

```
def caesar_cipher(input, key)
  letters = ('a'..'z').to_a
  input.each_char.map { |c| letters.include?(c) ?
    letters[(letters.index(c)+key) % 26] : c }.join
end

caesar_cipher("this is your brown dog", 2)
  #=> "vjku ku aqwt dtqyp fqi"
```

**#2**

```
def caesar_cipher(input, key)
  letters = ('a'..'z').to_a
  h = letters.zip(letters.rotate(key)).to_h
  h.default_proc = ->(_,k) { k }
  input.gsub(/./,h)
end

caesar_cipher("this is your brown dog", 2)
  #=> "vjku ku aqwt dtqyp fqi"
```

The hash `h` constructed in #2 equals:

```
h = letters.zip(letters.rotate(key)).to_h
  #=> {"a"=>"c", "b"=>"d", "c"=>"e", "d"=>"f", "e"=>"g", "f"=>"h",
  #   ...
  #    "u"=>"w", "v"=>"x", "w"=>"y", "x"=>"z", "y"=>"a", "z"=>"b"}
```

`h.default_proc = ->(_,k) { k }` causes

```
h[c] #=> c
```

if `c` is not a lowercase letter (e.g., a space, capital letter, number, punctuation, etc.)

Comment: You posted it just one second before me. Now that I think about it, `rotate` is indeed smarter than `cycle`. :)

Answer (score 2):

There is a more elegant way to loop repeating sequences in ruby. Meet [`Enumerable#cycle`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/Enumerable.html#method-i-cycle).

```
('a'..'z').cycle.take(50)
  # =>  ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j",
  #      "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t",
  #      "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z", "a", "b", "c", "d",
  #      "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n",
  #      "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "x"]
```

Therefore, translating a single *letter* given a *key* can be written as:

```
('a'..'z').cycle.take(letter.ord + key.to_i - 'a'.ord.pred).last
```

And the entire method can look prettier:

```
def caesar_cipher(phrase, key)
  phrase.each_char.map do |letter|
    ('a'..'z').cycle.take(letter.ord + key.to_i - 'a'.ord.pred).last
  end.join
end

puts caesar_cipher('abcxyz', 3) # => defabc
```

Note that this is slower than the alternative, but it also has the benefit that it's easier to read and the `key` can be any number.

Comment: You don't need to define the enumerator with `cycle` for each letter, and better to stab out a letter than taking the last element of an array you pull out. Also, use `each_char`.

Comment: @CarySwoveland, what do you mean by *stab out*? Also why `each_char`?

Comment: You are taking the first x elements of `('a'..'z').cycle` (an array) and then taking last element of the array. Instead, just "stab" out the element of the enumerator at offset x. `phrase.chars` creates a temporary array; `phrase.each_char` creates an enumerator. Define `enum = ('a'..'z').cycle` before `phrase...`.

Comment: @CarySwoveland, I just don't know what "stab out" means. :~ Are you proposing that I `enum = ('a'..'z').cycle; enum.drop(key.to_i - 'a'.ord.pred)` and then use that `enum`? Unfortunately, `drop` wouldn't work. Also I know that `chars` creates an array and `each_char` creates an enumerator, but since I'm iterating through all of them, is there really a difference?

Comment: There doesn't appear to be a built-in in `Enumerator` or `Enumerable` to return an element of an enumerator at a given offset. Re: `each_char` it just avoids using memory for a temporary array. It doesn't matter here, but could if `phrase` were big. Good night.

Comment: Ah, you can "stab out" the `n=5`th element of an enumerator like so: `(0..10).cycle.with_index.find { |_,i| i==n }.first #=> 4`. This avoids the construction of a temporary array.